# Can't load external page inside hide/show div

Tags: jquery

My problem is:

i have some external page `fotos1.asp` where i call inside a `#fotos_dentro` from my `index.asp` when i click in the main photo of the party.

This main photo is inside an another div `#fotos`. And i use some jquery scripts to work with this.

and i have some scrollBar script to.. so what's happen?

My `fotos1.asp` dont apear inside the `#fotos_dentro`.

Here is my script:

```
$(function(){

   $("#fotos_dentro").hide();

    $('.fotos1').live('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var h = $(this).attr('href');
        $.get(h, function() {
            $("#fotos").fadeOut("slow", function() {
                $("#fotos_dentro").show(function(){
                    $(this).load(h).fadeIn("slow", function(){
                        $("#mcs_container").mCustomScrollbar("vertical",400,"easeOutCirc",1.05,"30","yes","yes",10);
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    });
});
```

here is my HTML:

```
<div class="conteudo">
    <!-- comeco sroll -->
    <div id="mcs_container" class="rolagem">
        <div class="customScrollBox">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="content">
                <div id="fotos_dentro"></div>
                <div id="fotos">
                    <!-- HERE IS MY ASP PROGRAMMING -->
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="dragger_container">
                <div class="dragger"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- fim scroll -->
</div>
```

Here is my site: http://www.alsite.com.br/luxxx/ - click on `GALERIA` to see the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.load` is redundant in this case, just append the returned html.

```
$(function() {

    $("#fotos_dentro").hide();

    $('.fotos1').live('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var h = $(this).attr('href');
        $.get(h, function(data) {
            $("#fotos").fadeOut("slow", function() {
                $("#fotos_dentro").html(data).fadeIn("slow", function() {
                    $("#mcs_container").mCustomScrollbar("vertical", 400, "easeOutCirc", 1.05, "30", "yes", "yes", 10);
                });
            });
        });
    });
});​
```

Comment: this works very nice... so... now.. how i can show my `#fotos` and hide the `#fotos_dentro` from this external page?